# I18nLanguages does not work?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

Created API link: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&hl=en_US&id=EaNbiWgaoIs&key=[mykey]

But in paragraph "localized" did not translate text.

What am I doing wrong, and in general it can be translated? Or is it a glitch Google?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list):

> If localized resource details are available in that language, the
>   resource's snippet.localized object will contain the localized values.
>   However, if localized details are not available, the snippet.localized
>   object will contain resource details in the resource's default
>   language.

In this case, that video just doesn't have localized details for English.